# Comparing dates in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, date-math

Suppose I have a standard `Post.first.created_at` datetime. Can I compare that directly with a datetime in the format `2009-06-03 16:57:45.608000 -04:00` by doing something like:

```
Post.first.created_at > Time.parse("2009-06-03 16:57:45.608000 -04:00")
```

**Edit:** Both fields are **datetimes**, **not dates**.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, you can use comparison operators to compare dates e.g.:

```
irb(main):018:0> yesterday = Date.new(2009,6,13)
=> #<Date: 4909991/2,0,2299161>
irb(main):019:0> Date.today > yesterday
=> true
```

But are you trying to compare a date to a datetime?

If that's the case, you'll want to convert the datetime to a date then do the comparison.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Just a note: Comparing rails own datetime objects against others can give very unexpected results. Notably... see below:
    `p.created_at # Fri, 28 Aug 2015 21:45:14 UTC +00:00`
    `p.updated_at # Fri, 28 Aug 2015 21:45:14 UTC +00:00 `
    `p.created_at == p.updated_at # false`
So you have to do this... `p.created_at.to_i == p.updated_at.to_i # true`
more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599792/comparing-identical-datetime-objects-in-ruby-why-are-these-two-datetime-nows

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can compare directly the value of a `created_at` ActiveRecord date/time field with a regular `DateTime` object (like the one you can obtain parsing the string you have).

In a project i have a Value object that has a created_at datetime object:

```
imac:trunk luca$ script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.2)
>> Value.first.created_at
=> Fri, 12 Jun 2009 08:00:45 CEST 02:00
>> Time.parse("2009-06-03 16:57:45.608000 -04:00")
=> Wed Jun 03 22:57:45 0200 2009
>> Value.first.created_at > Time.parse("2009-06-03 16:57:45.608000 -04:00")
=> true
```

The created_at field is defined as:

```
  create_table "values", :force => true do |t|
    [...]
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end
```

N.B. if your field is a date and not a datetime, then you need to convert it to a time:

```
Post.first.created_at.to_time > Time.parse("2009-06-03 16:57:45.608000 -04:00")
```

or parse a date:

```
Post.first.created_at > Date.parse("2009-06-03 16:57:45.608000 -04:00")
```

otherwise you'll get a:

```
ArgumentError: comparison of Date with Time failed
```