# Ruby on Rails - Date Comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, date-comparison

I am trying to compare dates for an app in rails. I have tried this link [Comparing dates in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992431/comparing-dates-in-rails). But this is not what I want, suppose I have a filter according to dates, then I am doing

`<% jobs = @user.jobs.where(:curr_date => (Date.today))%>`

Here, curr_date is a "date" attribute chosen by me.

This code works for entries which have today's date, but if I want all entries which have date between today and a week before, what should I do?

Thanx! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```
jobs = @user.jobs.where(:curr_date => (DateTime.now..1.week.ago))
```

Updated to `DateTime.now` or you can also use `Date.today.to_time` otherwise there will be an error for comparing a `Date` and a `Time`

Comment: Also note, that doing this on the view (as your question sugests) is not good practice

Comment: thanx for replying, but I get some "bad value for range" error. Instead, I tried:   `<% jobs = @user.jobs.all(:conditions =>['curr_date > ?',Date.today-7])%>` and it worked for me. :) Kindly tell me the intricacies involved, if possible.

Comment: Just use (Date.today.to_time..1.week.ago) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like that should work:

`<% jobs = @user.jobs.where(['curr_date < ? AND curr_date > ?', Date.today, 1.week.ago])) %>`

Comment: I think the code has minor mistake.It should be ['curr_date <= ? AND curr_date >= ?', Date.today, 1.week.ago]

Comment: Well, the question is was it opened or closed interval :)

Answer (score 1):

comparison_date_1 <=> comparison_date_2 might be useful to to you which returns -1,1,0 accordingly and you can populate them......

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this in a console but I think it should work:

```
# You need to implement the #week_before method
@user.jobs.where(:curr_date => (Date.week_before..Date.today))
```

[Active Record Querying - Array Conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions) Check under Range conditions (2.2.2)

Comment: The `IN` is not valid syntax, that should be `=>`