# Comparing identical DateTime objects in ruby -- why are these two DateTime.now's not equal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a rails app, I have model code of the form:

```
def do_stuff(resource)
  models = Model.where(resource: resource)
  operated_at = DateTime.now

  models.each { |model| some_operation(model, operated_at) }

  some_other_operation models, operated_at
end

def some_operation(model, operated_at)
  model.date_time_field = operated_at
  model.save
end

def some_other_operation(models, operated_at)
  models.each do |model|
    if model.date_time_field < operated_at
      # do something
    end    
  end
end
```

The 'do something' block of some_other_operation will always be executed, in this situation.  Even stranger, if I set this up in the console without all the defined functions, the comparison works as expected. Example:

```
> model = Model.first
> time_var = DateTime.now
> model.last_imported_at = time_var
=> Fri, 25 Oct 2013 21:14:06 +0000
> model.save
=> true
> model.last_imported_at < time_var
=> false
> model.last_imported_at == time_var
=> true
```

Finally, if, in `some_other_operation` I instead compare in the following way:

```
if model.date_time_field.to_i < operated_at.to_i
  # do something
end
```

the 'do something' block is reached only when expected.  I suspect this is because the `to_i` method will drop the fractions of a second defined on the DateTime object, and the `operated_at` variable is actually being redefined as `DateTime.now` for each methods' scope. If this is the case, then I guess my question is how do I force `operated_at` to not be redefined for each scope?

Comment: It could be that the act of saving the model causes the `seconds_fraction` part of the DateTime to be truncated. (I haven't verified that though.)

Comment: Sorry, rails newbie, I face these kind of issue, just wondering are `localtime` or `timezone` things also had a effect toward this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible clue; the act of saving and reloading truncates the `seconds_fraction` part of the DateTime. The date field becomes an instance of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. Just saving without reloading doesn't do this; the real DateTime object is still there.

```
2.0.0-p195 :001 > dt            =  DateTest.create
2.0.0-p195 :002 > right_now     =  DateTime.now
2.0.0-p195 :004 > dt.created_at =  right_now
2.0.0-p195 :005 > dt.created_at == right_now
 => true 

2.0.0-p195 :006 > dt.save
2.0.0-p195 :007 > dt.created_at == right_now
 => true 

2.0.0-p195 :008 > dt = DateTest.find(dt.id)
2.0.0-p195 :009 > dt.created_at == right_now
 => false
```

Edit: *of course* calling `models.each` is going to load the models there and then because of the lazy loading behaviour. Props to the other answerer. As an experiment, try setting `models` to  `Model.where(resource: resource).to_a`.

Answer (score 1):

You have three separate methods defined above with three separate operated_at local variables. Local variables are limited to the scope of the method which defines them.

You need to define instance variables, which persist throughout a class. For example, you could:

```
def Model
  attr_accessor :operated_at

  def do_stuff(resource)
    models = Model.where(resource: resource)
    operated_at = DateTime.now

    models.each { |model| some_operation(model, operated_at) }

    some_other_operation models, operated_at
  end

  def some_operation(model, operated_at)
    model.date_time_field = operated_at
    model.save
  end

  def some_other_operation(models, operated_at)
    models.each do |model|
      if model.date_time_field < operated_at
        # do something
      end    
    end
  end
end
```

This would enable you to access operated_at throughout all of the class methods.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this problem is due to the lazy scope that you use: `models = Model.where(resource: resource)`

models is a proxy collection and will be resolved by rails at some point and might be re-evaluated without you knowing exactly.

so when you change an attribute and you don't `reload` the object before checking a property it might not be up to date.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Converting the DateTime objects to integers  renders the comparison true, as expected; which, unless I am misunderstanding, implies that the issue is not with the the `date_time_field` referencing an older, non-updated version of the model, but rather that multiple, separate (and slightly different) `DateTime.now`'s are being used when only a single instance is intended.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.now doesn't work for comparison with Database datetime object.

Example:

1. If you have the server running in Pacific Time Zone, you will expect to get the

> > DateTime.now  -->
> >     Fri, 25 Oct 2013 15:28:21 -0800
> >     
> >     (Daylight Saving Time in October supposed to be -7 hour from UTC, but somehow the datetime.now always give you -8 from UTC)

1. I think if you use Time.zone.now instead of DateTime.now will give you the correct comparison.

> > Time.zone.now -->
> >     Fri, 25 Oct 2013 15:27:17 PDT -07:00