# Compare datetime objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to compare two DateTime objects. However, I don't quite understand the result.

```
DateTime.parse("2014-09-14 01:12:03 +0200")
>> Sun, 14 Sep 2014 01:12:03 +0200   

Foo.order("created_at").last.created_at.to_datetime
>> Sun, 14 Sep 2014 01:12:03 +0200
```

But

```
Foo.order("created_at").last.created_at.to_datetime === DateTime.parse("2014-09-14 01:12:03 +0200")
true

Foo.order("created_at").last.created_at.to_datetime > DateTime.parse("2014-09-14 01:12:03 +0200")
true
```

Why is the result of the `>` comparison not `false`? (Rails 4.0.9)

Edit: I got it working using the `===` operator. But it still returns `true` when I use the `>` operator.

Comment: Looks like you might get some hints here [Comparing dates in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992431/comparing-dates-in-rails)

Comment: What's the class of each of your objects?

Comment: @MaxWilliams It's both a DateTime object. Please see my updated question.

Comment: I was running similar DateTime comparisons in a local console and was able to replicate what you're seeing (and now I'm really curious as to why). However, one thing I was able to do to get the comparisons working correctly was to convert the DateTime objects to integers for the comparison (time1.to_i > time2.to_i). That seemed to get the expected results from the comparison operators but I'm very interested why those two seemingly identical DateTimes did not compare correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator `===` is defined in Date class in Ruby which is parent class of DateTime. Operator `===` Returns true if they are the same day which is the case in your example. See [description](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)

Now to answer other part of your question about comparing two DateTime, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599792/comparing-identical-datetime-objects-in-ruby-why-are-these-two-datetime-nows). Which states that the act of saving and reloading datetime in database truncates the seconds_fraction part of the DateTime.

You can verify that in your rails console by below code -

```
obj1 = Foo.order("created_at").last.created_at.to_datetime
obj2 = DateTime.parse("2014-09-14 01:12:03 +0200")

obj1.sec > obj2.sec #comparing seconds, returns false. Both equal
obj1.sec_fraction > obj2.sec_fraction #should return true. Not equal.
```